# How to set LD_PRELOAD in systemd

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, hook, systemd, ld-preload

I want to hook some functions in libssl with `LD_PRELOAD` in systemd.

In systemd file I put

```
ExecStart=/etc/myscript.sh
```

and in /etc/myscript.sh I put

```
#!/bin/sh
LD_PRELOAD=/lib/inject_libssl.so /bin/run
```

When I look at `/proc/RUN_PID/maps` I can see that inject_libssl.so is realy injected to the process but the original libssl.so is loaded before the the injected library, so my hook doesn't work.

I olso tried

```
ExecStart=/bin/run 
Environment="LD_PRELOAD=/lib/inject_libssl.so"
```

But I got the same results.

If I run `LD_PRELOAD=/lib/inject_libssl.so curl https://google.com` the injected libssl works well.

Why is that please?

Comment: Does `LD_PRELOAD=/lib/inject_libssl.so /bin/run` work as expected when executed interactively (i.e., in a shell, similar to how you checked injection with `curl`)?

Comment: @AlexO Yes. Work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this script to see which one will be loaded ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
  
cp /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so /tmp/inject_libssl.so
LD_PRELOAD=/tmp/inject_libssl.so /bin/run
```

Can you also try to put your .so in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` ?

Comment: Then change `bash` to `sh` and retry.

Comment: Still the original libssl is loaded before my injected libssl

Comment: Does `/proc/RUN_PID/maps` give the order of loading ?

Comment: Yes, I can see that `libssl.so` is loaded to lower address then `inject_libssl.so` that tell me the order of loading

Comment: If you put `LD_PRELOAD=/lib/inject_libssl.so curl https://google.com` in systemd, does it work ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is probably that `systemd` runs your script / binary in set-user-ID mode. According to the [dynamic linker documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ld.so), `LD_PRELOAD` support is limited then:

> For set-user-ID/set-group-ID ELF binaries, preload pathnames
> containing slashes are ignored, and libraries in the standard search
> directories are loaded only if the set-user-ID permission bit is
> enabled on the library file.

So you need to copy your library to the proper place and provide the permission accordingly. You might be able to work around this with a specific `User=` setting or by using a wrapper.

Comment: I don't sure that I understand you offer but 1)my library is injected not ignored.   2)how can I verify of `systemd`runs my ELF in set-user-ID mode?

Comment: Handling of `LD_PRELOAD` within `systemd` environments depends on your particular version of `ld.so` and `systemd`. E.g., the `ld.so` version on Arch Linux has a special [secure execution mode](https://man.archlinux.org/man/ld.so.8.en) that disables `LD_PRELOAD` support in certain environments.

Comment: how can I read that configuration on my system and loaded(is that write on /etc/*** ?)? And as I wrote in the post, my inject_libssl.so is loaded but loaded after the original so

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the suggestions in this and some locations on the web I could find. None worked except the wrapper. I added the `SETUID` bit, copied the `.so` file first to `/tmp`, then to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, then tried to include the library without slashes, i.e.

```
...
[Service]
Environment="MARK=10 LD_PRELOAD=mark.so"
...
```

Still no-go. An interactive run, however, worked as expected (I was setting up a route-jail for `nginx`). The `LD_PRELOAD` also could not be placed in front of the executable name on the `ExecStart` line, as it resulted in an error.

In the end, creating a wrapper worked, and the `systemctl` operation still seems to be normal, i.e., `systemctl` brings up the service, shows its status, and shuts it down as expected. I ended up with:

```
...
[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/nginx.pid
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g 'daemon on; master_process on;'
ExecStart=/tmp/testnginx.sh
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon on; master_process on;' -s reload
ExecStop=-/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid
TimeoutStopSec=5
KillMode=mixed
...
```

The only line modified in the `systemd` script is `ExecStart`. The wrapper (which I'll move to some more sensible location from `/tmp`), is simple:

```
#!/bin/bash

MARK=10 LD_PRELOAD=mark.so /usr/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon on; master_process on;'
```

The wrapper is just `chmod 755`; it doesn't have the `SETUID` bit set.

This is on Ubuntu 22.04.